# Laravel Custom Message

Tags: laravel, error-handling

Hi I am working with custom validation with laravel I am new in this right now my controller code is mention this is how I am validating the upload file.
**Everything is working but I have issue displaying custom message on view page 
it shows the default message not my custom message** Please have a look and let me know if I am doing something wrong.

```
$this->validate(
          $request, [
            'project_file.*' => 'required|size:2048',
            ],
            [
               'project_file.required' => 'Upload File Field Is Required',
               'project_file.max' => 'Upload File Field Must Be 2MB',
            ]
        );
        $messages = [
        'required' => 'The File should not be more then 2Mb',
        'size'    => 'The must be exactly Mb.',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

        if($validator->fails()) {
          return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
        }
```

My View code to display error is:

```
@if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>{!! implode('', $errors->all('<div>:message</div>')) !!}</strong>
</div>

@endif
```

Comment: Use custom request class to handle error messages. It's a better approach

Comment: can you plz modify the code @sagar

Comment: what is that default message showing??

Comment: (The project_file.0 must be 2048 kilobytes.) This message

Comment: 'size'    => 'The :attribute must be exactly :size.'
Add this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the issue might be because you have not passed the **field name** placeholder in the messages array.

You can add [custom error messages](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-error-messages) for your validations. You can pass a third parameter `Validator::make` method.

```
$messages = [ 'required' => 'The :field should not be more then 2Mb' ];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

> The `:field` place-holder will be replaced by the field name

Adding **custom error messages** only for a **specific field** using **dot operation**

```
$messages = [
    'file.required' => 'The image should not be more then 2Mb',
];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's better approach not to write validation logic in the controller because it results fat controller and quite messy controller so you can use separate request class to do in better way.

At first, use following command in console to create custom validation request class like this,

```
php artisan make:request PostRequest
```

Now, a file named `PostRequest.php` will be created at the `app/Http/Requests/` in that file you should make validation like following.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PostRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
       'project_file.*' => 'required|max:2048',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
      'required' => 'Upload File Field Is Required',
      'max'     => 'The File should not be more then 2Mb',
    ];
}
}
```

Now, function in which form request is passed you have to change Request to PostRequest like this so that validation is performed automatically.

```
public function post(PostRequest $request){
   //
}
```

Comment: Does this answer help ? If so then please close the question by accepting it :D

Comment: i have modify my code i was missing something thanks for the help